# AngularJS: Access value of data binding from within directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I am trying to access the value a data binding inside a directive executed after an ng-repeat.

Here is my html:

```
<div ng-repeat="(version, data) in versions" rszvers>
  <div class="hidden_div">{{version}}</div>
  <div><p>{{data.opts.a}}</p></div>
  <div><p>{{data.opts.b}}</p></div>
  <div><p>{{data.opts.c}}</p></div>
</div>
```

And my directive:

```
 .directive('rszvers', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var p = element.find("p").contents();
    angular.forEach(p, function(value, key) {
      console.log(key);
      console.log(value.textContent);
    });
  };
 })
```

I tried to access the value of my `<p>` with the value.textContent (which shows the correct value in the console), but of course I only retrieve `{{data.opts.a}}`.
I tried to eval or parse this binding with no luck.

I know there must be an easy way to do this but I cannot wrap my head around this.
Can you please shed some light on what I am missing and how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it via `scope` e.g:

```
.directive('rszvers', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
   console.log(scope.data.opts.a, scope.data.opts.b, scope.data.opts.c);
 });
```

Comment: Well, that was easy indeed... Thank you!